# how to maintain datatable for grid with in a grid

Tags: datatable

I'm working with grid within a  grid. I want to maintain dt. I don't understand how to maintain child grid in datatable please help me.

```
for (int jj = 0; jj < grvQuestions.Rows.Count; jj++)
{
    DataRow dr;
    GridViewRow row = grvQuestions.Rows[jj];
    dr = dtval.NewRow();

    for (int ii = 0; ii < row.Cells.Count; ii++)
    {
        dr[ii] = row.Cells[ii].Text;
    }

    dtval.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

I tried to import data but this didn't work.

Comment: Question is a bit vague.  In what way did it not work?

Comment: What language are you using? I'm assuming C# but I could be wrong.

Comment: i have a gridview in that  nested grid is there.. for that i should matain datatable. im using # only

Comment: i need to maintain nested datatable..